# scrollBehavior not called on hash change?

Tags: nuxt3

I have a Nuxt3 app with a plugin that change the scrollBejavior:

plugins/router.scrollBejavior.js

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.$router.options.scrollBehavior = (to, from, savedPosition) => {
        console.log('scroll')
        if (savedPosition) return savedPosition

        if (from && from.path == to.path && to.hash) {
            const hash = to.hash.replace('#', '')
            const el = document.querySelector(`[id="${hash}"]`)
            if (!el) return

            if ('scrollBehavior' in document.documentElement.style) {
                return { left: 0, top: el.offsetTop - 100, behavior: 'smooth' }
            } else {
                return { left: 0, top: el.offsetTop - 100 }
            }
        }

        return { left: 0, top: 0, behaviour: 'smooth' }
    }
})
```

I have a page with multiple id location (#hashtags) along with a table of content that list these location.

Loading the page triggers the `scrollBehavior` (the console.log is well displayed), but when I click on any link in the table of content, the scroll occurs, but the `scrollBehavior` is not called. The links are in `<NuxtLink :to="{hash: '#id'}">`

I tried also programmatically, by calling `$router.push({ hash: '#id' })` and it's the same, `scrollBehavior` is not called.

Why is that? How can I trigger `scrollBehavior` for changes on the same page?

Comment: In some places you've used `scrollBejavior` and in others you've used `scrollBehavior`. Is the first one an error?

Answer (score 0):

That is an old implementation and I think the recommended way to do it is by using the `app/router.options.ts`

[Documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/custom-routing#router-options)

[Github thread](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/22663)

Here is a simple example of `scrollBehavior` on multiple hashes

`app/router.options.ts`

```js
import type { RouterConfig } from '@nuxt/schema'

// https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/routeroptions.html
export default <RouterConfig>{
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        console.log(to)
        if (to.path === '/') {
            if (to.hash) {
                const el = document.querySelector(`${to.hash}`)
                if (el) {
                    el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The logic will run on the home page only because I set the `to.path` to `/` as an example.

`~/pages/index.vue`

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>

</script>
<template>
  <main>
    <div class="nav">
      <NuxtLink
        v-for="link in 10"
        :key="link"
        :to="`/#section${link}`"
      >
        {{ link }}
      </NuxtLink>
    </div>
    <section
      :id="`section${section}`"
      v-for="section in 10"
      :key="section"
    >
      <h1>Section {{ section }}</h1>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css">
.nav {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

section:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
</style>
```

Tested and it works.